# storing data to sharedpreferences using json

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-preferences

I am working on a small Android App!

I have a class MyPref

```
public class MyPref{
{
java.util.Calendar cal;
int id;
String name;
//some more methods and constructor
}
```

I need to store an array of MyPref objects to sharedpreferences...

```
java.util.ArrayList<MyPref> array=new java.util.ArrayList<MyPref>();
array.add(//MyPref object);
array.add(//MyPref object);
```

now how can I store this ArrayList object to sharedpreferences..
I tried..

```
JSONObject o=new JSONObject();
o.put("list",array);
SharedPreferences s=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edt=s.edit();
edt.putString("mylist",o.toString());
edt.commit();
```

but this doesn't worked!
is there any other alternative??
plz help me..
thanx in advace..

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it doesn't work."  Is there a logcat error, a ANR, some sort of visible error, or you can't see anything, what happened...

Comment: its getting java.lang.ClassCasteException on String

Comment: you're not saying what line the error is on.  People can try to figure out from your code, but you'll get more help if you specify where the error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject o=new JSONObject();
o.put("list",array);
```

I may be wrong but I'm pretty sure you can't use `JSONObject.put(...)` to put an arbitrary Java object into a `JSONObject`. From the docs...

> public JSONObject put (String name, Object value)
>
> *value* a JSONObject, JSONArray, String, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double, NULL, or null. May not be NaNs or infinities.

There's no mention of being able to put a Java object of any other type and you're trying to put an `ArrayList<MyPref>`.